# How should the cloned sheep type be constructed

Tags: haskell, monads

So in the explanation of [Haskell monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads) they give the example of cloned sheeps.
However they only give a partial implementation of the data type:

```
type Sheep = ...

father :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
father = ...

mother :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
mother = ...
```

Which makes it quite difficult to experiment and understand the usage of the monads such as comb:

```
-- comb is a combinator for sequencing operations that return Maybe
comb :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
comb Nothing  _ = Nothing
comb (Just x) f = f x
```

How should `Sheep` be implemented?

Comment: In the article, the whole point is that it _doesn't matter_ how the type is implemented, as long as there are these two functions defined for it.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin that sounds absolutely logical *however* for me it is important to experiment with it and truly understand the extend of how it doesn't matter. As such a definition of which I can jump off would be helpful in my understanding. I guess it boils down to how I'm still having difficulty reading the type definitions (e.g. `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`) and actual implementations help with getting more feeling with it. And as for the answer given, the given definition is of `type` and the answer is of `data`, which I don't understand yet how this can happen.

Comment: "data" in `data` is short for "datatype". `data` does not create data, it creates types of data. (*<mumbling> yet another of countless cases of bad naming choices in Haskell </mumbling>*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is to address the clarification that you gave in the comments:

> the given definition is of `type` and the answer is of `data`, which I don't understand yet how this can happen.

---

Haskell has a few different ways of declaring types.

The `type` keyword is used to declare a *type alias* - similar to `typedef` or `using` in C++. One could, theoretically, as an exercise in futility, declare `Sheep` as an alias of `String`, with the implied understanding that the `String` would signify the sheep's name, and then there is a "global" list of parents for each sheep, which the `mother` and `father` functions would use for lookup:

```
type Sheep = String

allParents :: [(Sheep, (Sheep, Sheep))]
allParents =
  [ ("dolly", ("rufus", "peggy"))
  , ("peggy", ("ramses", "woolly"))
  , ...
  ]

mother :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
mother s = fst <$> lookup s allParents

father :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
father s = snd <$> lookup s allParents
```

But this would be *very* unusual and not functional at all. I think this would be a prime example of a [gorilla holding a banana and the entire jungle](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/19/you-wanted-banana/).

A more Haskell way of modeling the situation would be to declare `Sheep` as a data structure with (at least) two fields - `mother` and `father`. For this sort of thing, one uses the keyword `data`:

```
data Sheep = Sheep (Maybe Sheep) (Maybe Sheep)

father :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
father (Sheep f _) = f

mother :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
mother (Sheep _ m) = m
```

But defining these accessor functions for every field of your type is quite mundane, so Haskell has a shorter syntax for it:

```
data Sheep = Sheep { father :: Maybe Sheep, mother :: Maybe Sheep }
```

this would declare the same structure with two fields, *plus* automatically create the accessor functions that work the same way as in the previous example.

To preempt your next question, I should also mention a third way of defining types - `newtype`, which is like `data`, but only for structures with exactly one field, and is just a performance optimization.

---

Don't get hung up on the specific keyword used. The article just needed to make a point that there is this type and two functions to go with it, and it doesn't really matter how they're defined. The article had to use *some* keyword to make this point, and they chose `type`. A more or less arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 3):

One minimal implementation for `Sheep` is

```
data Sheep = Sheep {mother :: Maybe Sheep, father :: Maybe Sheep}
```

A more sane implementation, where you could have siblings (which can be distinguished by their `name`) would be

```
data Sheep = Sheep {name :: String, mother :: Maybe Sheep, father :: Maybe Sheep}
```

Comment: So as I would read this this is declaring a "datastructure" (sorry C++ programmer) which contains a mother, father and name, is that correct? But it does so using the `data` statement instead of the `type` one by the wiki.

Comment: @TarickWelling: `type` is used for a type *synonym*, `data` and `newtype` are used to define a new type.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `Sheep` truly doesn't matter. It's the definitions of `mother` and `father` that *use* the definition that is important. The following would work

```
type Sheep = Int

mother :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
mother 0 = Nothing
mother 1 = Nothing
mother n = Just (n `div` 2)

father :: Sheep -> MaybeSheep
father 0 = Nothing
father 1 = Nothing
father n = Just (n `mod` 2)
```

as would

```
type Sheep = String

mother :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
mother (x:_:rest) = Just [x]
mother _ = Nothing

father :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
father (_:x:rest) = Just [x]
father _ = Nothing
```

(In neither case am I too concerned about what `mother` and `father` *mean*; the point it to illustrate that the types are what matter.)

`comb` itself actually doesn't care what `mother` and `father` return; it simply handles the problem of trying to find the mother or father of a non-sheep. You can use `mother` and `father` with `comb` as long as they have the correct type.

```
comb (Just name) mother == mother name -- name :: Sheep, so mother name :: Maybe Sheep
comb Nothing mother == Nothing -- Nothing :: Maybe Sheep in both cases
```

Comment: Maybe. I didn't really put much thought into how the name was structured.  (If it's the concatenation of your parent's full names, you'd have to split the name in half, and the parents would be the first character of each half. Or something.)

Comment: Ah, right. Switched to `Just [x]` to avoid thinking too much about how the functions actually work, since type checking was the focus of the question.

Comment: reason I suggested `(x:rest)` is, with just `[x]` the chained application `mother >=> mother` is guaranteed to fail. :)